# What is the difference between ForEach in System.Linq and ForEach in WebGrease.Css.Extensions?

Tags: c#, linq

For example

**System.Linq**

```
dogs.ToList().ForEach(dog => Console.WriteLine(dog.Name));
```

**WebGrease.Css.Extensions**

```
dogs.ForEach(dog => Console.WriteLine(dog.Name));
```

Both appear to do the same thing, so what is the difference? Are there any performance differences? Also I think Linq may not allow a function call like I have mentioned above, but it does compile.

Comment: You can view this topic : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1064219/A-behavioural-difference-between-IEnumerable-ForEa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ForEach` is a member of `System.List<T>`, not part of Linq. The code you have provided will enumerate the items twice, once for the `ToList` call and once for the `ForEach`.

The WebGrease is an extension of `IEnumerable<T>` (see https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/27951506/). The code you have provided for that case will enumerate them once.